# AEM - Maven project does not copy apps components package

Tags: maven, package, pom.xml, aem

I'm using AEM 6.1 and using maven(3.3.3) to build and deploy projects. Whereas, the maven buiild installs my bundle package, with the java code. It is not copying my components and templates folder (in the apps folder).

I have added the paths in the filter.xml. Can someone provide me a sample POM or structure of how we can achieve copying of the components during the build?

Thanks!

Comment: you might be missing a maven resources plugin config, make sure that `src/main/content/jcr_root` is added as a resource and is available for packaging.

Answer (score 1):

Was your Maven project created from an archetype? If so, there should be a `autoInstallPackage` profile defined. I suspect you may be using `autoInstallBundle`, which would only install your OSGI bundle.

If it wasn't, you need to configure the `content-package-maven-plugin` to deploy the generated CRX package to a target instance.

There should be sufficient information in the official Adobe documentation for [managing packages with Maven](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/dev-tools/vlt-mavenplugin.html) but here's a sample config from Lazybone's aem-multimodule-project by ACS Commons.

Specify the contents of your CRX package:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
            <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <group>${packageGroup}</group>
                <filterSource>src/main/content/META-INF/vault/filter.xml</filterSource>
                <embeddeds>
                    <embedded>
                        <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${bundleArtifactId}</artifactId>
                        <target>/apps/${appsFolderName}/install</target>
                    </embedded>
                </embeddeds>
                <targetURL>http://\${crx.host}:\${crx.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Specify a profile to use in order to install the package:

```
    <profile>
        <id>autoInstallPackage</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install-content-package</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Source:
https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/lazybones-aem-templates/blob/master/templates/aem-multimodule-project/content/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks! I have done the same. But, for some reason, the /apps components package does not get deployed. I have added the path in filter.xml as well. BUt it hasn't helped

Comment: @calculus does your package contain anything other than your OSGI bundle? Could you please include the contents of your `filter.xml` as well as the configuration of the `content-package-maven-plugin`. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am now able to install the apps package. It was an issue with .content.xml files missing in some of the subfolders.

however, I have another issue now. Maybe I don't understand it properly. When I use 'clean install -P autoInstallPackage -e', the apps package gets installed. However, the java OSGI bundle is in installed state, saying missing org.json dependency (the pom in in ui.apps)

But when I use clean install -P autoInstallBundle -e, it install everything properly. (the pom is in bundle)

any inputs?